# How to read Evaluate Script timings in Chrome profiling/performance tab

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-profile

I've been told that my script is blocking the main thread on my client's site.

It's marked as `<script async...>` so it should not be a network block.

I ran the Chrome profiler and I don't really understand what I'm looking at, despite googling for explanations.

Here's a screenshot of the script in question:
[image]

I don't understand which part of the entire blue block is the "thread blocking part"

Here's the associated `Bottom-Up` table:
[image]

From the first image, the "thin line" spans from around 500ms to around 900ms, which is around 400ms of time, but in the Bottom-Up table, it says the total "Evaluate Script" time is 184.5ms.

So can I assume the "blocking" time of the script should be taken from the Bottom-Up table, coming up to be 184.5ms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. On the first screenshot we are looking at **Network** section. You can read how to make sense of it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#network).
   In short:

   > - The left line is everything up to the `Connection Start` group of events, inclusive. In other words, it's everything before `Request Sent`, exclusive.
   > - The light portion of the bar is `Request Sent` and `Waiting (TTFB)`.
   > - The dark portion of the bar is `Content Download`.
   > - The right line is essentially time spent **waiting for the main thread**

   So it's not about execution time.
2. I myself don't completely understand yet what the `Bottom-Up` tab of the Network section mean... [Maybe](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#bottom-up) it doesn't even have a direct connection to network request:

   > The `Bottom-Up` tab only displays activities **during** the selected portion of the recording

   *during* doesn't necessary mean *caused by*.
3. But anyway it's probably not what you're looking for. Take a look at the **Main** section, right after the end of the network request when finally **waiting for the main thread** is over and it's free and ready to execute the script you'll probably see a long bar - that's the time when your script is blocking the main thread.
   E.g look at the screenshot[image]

   - First `lux.js` is loaded (from the cache in this particular case).
   - Then it waits for the main thread (from 3117ms until 3128ms).
   - Then a `Task` starts (it is selected and pointed to with the small arrow, the big arrow points to the fact that `lux.js` is indeed begins its execution)
   - Some time is spent on `Compile Script`
   - And only then you can see a flame chart of script execution (in red circle)

   You can read more about this on the same page [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#analyze)

---

Also some extra info and insights on optimization an performance monitor usage can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/why-performance-matters) and in subsequent articles.